# RPX abbreviation expansion?

Tags: rpxnow, rpx

Does anyone know if [RPX](http://www.RPXNow.com/) is an abbreviation for something or just a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This FAQ](http://www.rpxwiki.com/FAQ) says:

> **What does RPX stand for?**
>
> Relying Party Accelerator.  From the OpenID 2.0 specification, a Relying Party is ...

Comment: Thx, seems like i didn't searched with the correct search terms. But the strange thing is, there is nog X in Relying Party Accelerator

Comment: The "Acc..." sounds a little bit like X in English, this kind of word trick is sometimes used to make the abbreviation look "flashier".

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://jsilverman.tumblr.com/post/282684256/janrain-rpx-ruby-on-rails-and-authlogic) site (no idea how credible) it is "Relying Party X".

Context - "...RPX takes advantage of this and provides a middleman for the user depending on which service they selected they would like to use to login. The name means Relying Party X"